# How do I cd to CDROM directory

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, cd

How do I `cd` to into the inner cdrom (VBOXADDITIONS) directory?

[image: how?]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You change directories to locations on a CDROM the same way you change directories on your hard drive or any other media.

By default the cdrom will probably be mounted in your `/media` directory.  It appears from your image that you might have already noticed this and have gotten fairly close.

When changing to a directory you have to be very careful to the spelling as well as the case of the letters.  A directory that has an upper case letter would be different from a directory with a lower case.

You can use the facility of Linux's completion by typing some of the characters and hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to complete the characters.  This can serve to help you get the spelling exact.  It has to be exact.

You might also consider using copy and paste to be sure to get the spelling and upper/lower case conditions more accurate.

In the case of the image you have above, typing `cd VB` then hitting the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key should have completed the spelling for you, then you could press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Also, looking at your image, you can't prefix the directory with just a forward-slash.  The forward-slash alone would indicate the root directory.

Comment: wow. Many thanks, using cd + tab worked like a charm. Now I can finally set a decent resolution for my VM.